# GCP LoadBalancer - How to Redirect on Failed Health Check

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-load-balancer

I am currently implementing a blue-green setup in GCE. Essentially what I'm doing is putting an nginx loadbalancer up as a backend to a GCP one, as switching the rules over to hit a different pool in nginx can be done quickly.

If there are no nginx backends available I want to error handle to a custom page held in a bucket but I can't see a clear way to do this with the standard health checks. Has anyone encountered this type of thing before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there are no nginx backends available I want to error handle to a
>   custom page held in a bucket

[Google Load Balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/) do not provide a feature for this requirement.

Comment: Thank you, I had more or less come to this conclusion. I will add this functionality to the more intelligent proxy / load balancer.